# Nexus3 cleanup policy is failing with NullPointerException

Tags: nexus3

I am using nexus:3.20.1-01.

I have setup cleanUp policy for maven-snapshot. as per below screen

[image: Cleanup policy]

**Preview of cleanup policy**, so this shows this policy is going to clean up shown file / directory.

[image]

**But when I run CleanUp Service**

[image]

I am getting an exception and it's not cleaning up the snapshots. below are the logs

```
2021-01-20 13:49:18,801+0000 INFO  [quartz-3-thread-20]  *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.cleanup.internal.task.CleanupTask - Task information:
2021-01-20 13:49:18,802+0000 INFO  [quartz-3-thread-20]  *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.cleanup.internal.task.CleanupTask -  ID: aff0b48e-b0d5-4247-8669-d903db5981d7
2021-01-20 13:49:18,802+0000 INFO  [quartz-3-thread-20]  *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.cleanup.internal.task.CleanupTask -  Type: repository.cleanup
2021-01-20 13:49:18,802+0000 INFO  [quartz-3-thread-20]  *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.cleanup.internal.task.CleanupTask -  Name: Cleanup service
2021-01-20 13:49:18,803+0000 INFO  [quartz-3-thread-20]  *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.cleanup.internal.task.CleanupTask -  Description: Run repository cleanup
2021-01-20 13:49:18,803+0000 INFO  [quartz-3-thread-20]  *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.cleanup.internal.task.CleanupTask - Starting cleanup
2021-01-20 13:49:18,803+0000 ERROR [quartz-3-thread-20]  *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.cleanup.internal.task.CleanupTask - Failed to run task 'Run repository cleanup'
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
        at org.sonatype.nexus.cleanup.internal.service.CleanupServiceImpl.findPolicies(CleanupServiceImpl.java:147)
        at org.sonatype.nexus.cleanup.internal.service.CleanupServiceImpl.cleanup(CleanupServiceImpl.java:99)
        at org.sonatype.nexus.cleanup.internal.service.CleanupServiceImpl.lambda$0(CleanupServiceImpl.java:89)
        at com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList.forEach(ImmutableList.java:407)
        at org.sonatype.nexus.cleanup.internal.service.CleanupServiceImpl.cleanup(CleanupServiceImpl.java:87)
        at org.sonatype.nexus.cleanup.internal.task.CleanupTask.execute(CleanupTask.java:46)
        at org.sonatype.nexus.scheduling.TaskSupport.call(TaskSupport.java:100)
        at org.sonatype.nexus.quartz.internal.task.QuartzTaskJob.doExecute(QuartzTaskJob.java:143)
        at org.sonatype.nexus.quartz.internal.task.QuartzTaskJob.execute(QuartzTaskJob.java:106)
        at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:202)
        at org.sonatype.nexus.quartz.internal.QuartzThreadPool.lambda$0(QuartzThreadPool.java:143)
        at org.sonatype.nexus.thread.internal.MDCAwareRunnable.run(MDCAwareRunnable.java:40)
        at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectRunnable.doRun(SubjectRunnable.java:120)
        at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectRunnable.run(SubjectRunnable.java:108)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2021-01-20 13:49:18,803+0000 INFO  [quartz-3-thread-20]  *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.cleanup.internal.task.CleanupTask - Task complete
```

Can someone please help me to find the issue.

Thanks

Alpesh

Answer (score 0):

I did not found anything related to this exception on any blogs.

**Solution:**

I just restart the nuxus docker and it is working.